# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘geoR’: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk'

Tags: r, spatial, geostatistics, geor

I am trying to use geoR package (v1.7-5.2) within RStudio (v1.0.153, running under Ubuntu 16.04 LTS), but it seems that some Tcl library needs to be reinstalled:

```
> library(geoR)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘geoR’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: 
    /builddir/vendor/build/lib/tcl8.6 ./lib/tcl8.6 ./lib/tcl8.6 ./library ./library ./tcl8.6.5/library ./tcl8.6.5/library

This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.
```

If I start geoR from command line then it starts fine.

```
> library(geoR)
--------------------------------------------------------------
 Analysis of Geostatistical Data
 For an Introduction to geoR go to http://www.leg.ufpr.br/geoR
 geoR version 1.7-5.2 (built on 2016-05-02) is now loaded
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstall **geoR** with dependencies = TRUE.

```
install.packages("geoR",dependencies = TRUE) 
library(geoR)
```

Comment: The error may be because of 'tcltk' package. Check capabilities()["tcltk"]

Comment: I get: 

`> capabilities()["tcltk"]`

`tcltk 
 TRUE`

Comment: I also checked that:

`sudo apt-get install tcl8.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
tcl8.6 is already the newest version (8.6.5+dfsg-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.`

Comment: Try reinstall RStudio. I had same issue with different package.